# Replicator Activity in sequential Mode for Approval WorkFlow in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow-activity

I am trying to create a Dcoument Approval WorkFlow, with Custom Task Edit infopath forms

Flow is ,When A Document is added into the List , it is assingned to User A , who is Orignator's Manager.

When User A Approves the document , it Assigned to User B for Approval.User B is fixed.

When User B has approved the document , then User B himself will assign the document to User C(Which means User C is dynamic and will be there at runtime).

When User C Approves it ,  A Task should be created for User , and work Flow should continue till User C Completes his Task.

Is Any of the Users , rejects the Task, The Workflow Should Stop.

How I implmented it ;

I created one Sequence Activity , as follows :

1. -create Task
2. -whileTaskNotComplete (onTaskChanged)
3. Complete Task

then Placed this Activity under Replicator Activity.

I am not sure how to set Replicator initialized and Child initialzed values .

I know replicator needs to be run for 3 times, but the last iterations value is not fixed, it is provided at runtime under second iteration.and under onTaskChange event of Activity.

How can I pass this value to workflow or next iteration?

second thing when i am setting any value for Apporver under replicator initialized method , it is assigning all the Tasks to same Approver which is set under initialized method.

could you please help me , I referred the videos http://www.shillier.com/Videos/MultipleTasks.wmv, but it is for Parallel mode , I need in sequential mode.

Thanks in advance.

Azra

Answer (score 0):

I would start splitting it up in a state machine:
1 Start
2 Create and Assign Task
3 Wait for approval
4 End
in the "Wait for approval" you check for your conditions and then set a global variable for the next approver in line (make sure it's persisted) and set the state to "Create and Assign Task". Until you are done with your list.
1->2->3->(->2)->4